# Macbook Pro Logicboard Replaced - How to know if replaced logic board is a new or used one?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, logicboard

I have a Macbook Pro 2016 model (Touchbar). Few days ago, I got a critical upgrade error and the mac wasn't starting.

I went to the service center and they replaced the logicboard. My mac is running fine now.

The serial number has been changed which i know is expected.

My Question is - How do I know if the service center has inserted a new logicboard or just replaced it with some other unused Mac's logicboard on my machine?

I checked the serial number on https://checkcoverage.apple.com/coverage and this is what it returns:

```
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
Purchase Date: August 2017
Serial Number: XXXXXXX

Coverage Expired
```

Does that mean the service center just used some 2017 model macbook and placed the logicboard on my laptop?

What should https://checkcoverage.apple.com/coverage return for a new logicboard?

Should I be expecting a `Purchase Date: July 2023`, since the repair was done this month?

Comment: That’s a 6 year old machine and out of warranty so it’s unlikely that new units are available to be used as replacements.  What did the repair center tell you?

Answer (score 1):

When I had my logicboard replaced, Apple sent me an email that included these words:

> Note: The items identified above have been exchanged by Apple for new
> or refurbished parts or products.
>
> All Apple products come with a one-year limited warranty and up to 90
> days of complimentary telephone technical support.

I don't think there's any way to tell or know if the part has previously been in another Mac; but if it has it will be 'refurbished', meaning thoroughly tested.

As said in the comments, Apple is not still making new ones, so anything will have been on the shelf for some time.

Either way, you'll have 1 year of warranty, before you'd need AppleCare to cover any further work.

If you got your repair from a third-party repair shop, then you'll need to check with them how long they guarantee their work for; plus any statutory rights in your location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you see when you cross check your new serial number on https://checkcoverage.apple.com/coverage?